# Tomcat server shows a 404 error when using Servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to write a simple servlet and it's not working and I can't figure out why. The code is very simple but somehow it's not working, and it's driving me nuts.

Here's the index.jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JavaEE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello JavaEE World</h1>
    <form action="helloServlet" method="post">
        Enter a number: <input type="text" name="number" size="5" />
            <input type="submit" value="Call Servlet" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the servlet file:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("helloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HelloServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();
        write.println("OMG");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String number = request.getParameter("number");
        PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();
        write.println("Number: " + number);
        write.flush();
    }
}
```

But somehow it's not working. I provided the pictures below if anyone care.

[Servlet File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHpJ3.png)

[index.jsp File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIQxM.png)

[index.jsp on Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsDuJ.png)

[Error image when submitting form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXDF3.png)

[Pom.xml if anyone care](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Hk3.png)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. I just started learning JavaEE development and don't know where to start. Which would you recommend learning first for a beginner like me? Thanks a lot (I learned Java Core).

Comment: I figured that I should learn something basic first before jumping into a framework, but it seems that this is not working. I'll definitely look into the Spring MVC next. Thank you for your time bro. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the annotation to this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", urlPatterns = { "/helloServlet" })
```